# Correct and Efficient Way to read the Elements Column Wise

Tags: java

> I am unable to find the correct way of reading the elements column wise.

**Input** is a List which contains 10 list and these 10 list contains elements having variable Column Size

**What I did**

Task1: Adding 10 List into a SingleList.

Task2: Finding the maximum size a column can have so that I can apply the loop till that Column.

Task 3
    Retrieving the List ColumnWise.

Code:
 //Task 1 Adding 10 List into a SingleList

```
    List<List<Integer>> outer=new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Integer> innerSize=new ArrayList<Integer>();
    List<Integer> inner=null;
     int ar[][]=new int[10][];
     int ar1[] =new int[ar.length];
      for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
      {
          System.out.println("Enter the Size of the list "+i);
             String s1=sc.next();

             int N=Integer.parseInt(s1); //Calculate the Size:
              inner=new ArrayList<Integer>();
              innerSize.add(N);
         for(int j=0;j<N;j++)
         {
              System.out.println("Enter the Elements of the list "+i);

           inner.add(Integer.parseInt(sc.next()));
         }
         System.out.println(inner);
         outer.add(inner);
      }
      System.out.println(outer);

      Task 2 
      System.out.println("Finding the maximum element");
      Integer max=null;
     Iterator<Integer> ltr=innerSize.listIterator();
      if(ltr.hasNext())
      {
          Integer element=(Integer)ltr.next();
             max=element;
            while(ltr.hasNext())
            {
                Integer element1=(Integer)ltr.next();
                if(element1>max)
                {
                    max=element1;
                }
            }
      }
      System.out.println("Maximum Element is"+max);

     //Task 3
      //Retrieving the List ColumnWise.
      Iterator ltr1=outer.listIterator();

      for(int j=0;j<max;j++)
      {

              while(ltr1.hasNext())
              {
                  List l0tol9=(List)ltr1.next(); //I have one list taken from the 10 lists.
                  Iterator ltr2=l0tol9.listIterator();
                    while(ltr2.hasNext())
                    {
                        Integer i1=(Integer)ltr2.next();
                        if(i1!=null)
                        {
                            System.out.println(i1);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
              }

          }
```

Input:Lets say I got this list from user:(outerList with max Column Size 2)

```
[[1], [1], [1, 2], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1]] //outerlist
```

Expected Output
   is

```
1
1  
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
2
```

Output Shown:(Only 1st Column)

```
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an easy way to browse 2-D Lists column-wise :

```
int maxColSize = outer.stream().mapToInt(List::size).max().orElse(0);
for (int y=0; y<maxColSize; y++) {
    for (int x=0; x<outer.size(); x++) {
        List<Integer> currentInner = outer.get(x);
        if (currentInner.size() > y) {
            System.out.println(currentInner.get(y));
        }
    }
}
```

You can try it [here](http://ideone.com/mKBj8x).

---

If you can't use Java8, substitute the first line with the following :

```
int maxColSize=0;
for (List<Integer> row : outer) { maxColSize = Math.max(maxColSize, row.size()); }
```

Comment: Thankx for the efficient code but if I want to do this through Java 7.

Comment: @user6389648 I've added code for Java7. You should specify when you can't use the latest Java version, Java 8 has been out for 2 years now and you should expect to get code for it unless you specify otherwise.

Comment: Thankx Aaron for the Code.And Sorry I have not mentioned it you have moved my knowledge to a great level.I have a lot of Questions too  I will ask in a seperate thread which is related to streams as I am new to it.